# if else condition in odoo 9 py

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I have a method to send mail from Odoo 9, this is my code:

```py
@api.multi
@api.depends('xquotationtrans_discount')
def draft_quotation(self):

    self.xquotationtrans_discount <= 30
    self.ensure_one()
    self.state ='approved'
    template = self.env.ref('contract_e.quotation_gm_mail_template', False)
    mail = self.env['mail.template'].browse(template.id)
    mail.send_mail(self.id, force_send=True)


    self.xquotationtrans_discount >= 30
    self.ensure_one()
    template = self.env.ref('contract_e.quotation_vp_mail_template', False)
    mail = self.env['mail.template'].browse(template.id)
    mail.send_mail(self.id, force_send=True)
```

How to make if else condition if my `discount` is `<= 30`, it can send mail to GM, and `if >= 30`, it can send mail to VP?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('xquotationtrans_discount')
def draft_quotation(self):

    if self.xquotationtrans_discount <= 30:
        self.ensure_one()
        self.state ='approved'
        template = self.env.ref('contract_e.quotation_gm_mail_template', False)
    else:
        self.ensure_one()
        template = self.env.ref('contract_e.quotation_vp_mail_template', False)

    mail = self.env['mail.template'].browse(template.id)
    mail.send_mail(self.id, force_send=True)
```